# Problem authenticating SOAP usernameToken with Apache CXF

Tags: java, soap, cxf, ws-security

I'm trying to develop a SOAP web service under `Apache CXF 3.0.4`, but i'm having trouble authenticating the `UsernameToken` included in every SOAP message header using WS-SecurityPolicy.
According to the [documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-securitypolicy.html), WS-SecurityPolicy is automatically enabled if the `cxf-rt-ws-policy` and `cxf-rt-ws-security` modules are available on the `classpath`. It does the necessary work to handle security, after a proper
configuration.
I do configuration through Endpoint Property Annotations, in
the following way:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", name = "MyService")

@EndpointProperties(value = {
        @EndpointProperty(key = "ws-security.callback-handler", value = "org.tempuri.ServerPasswordCallback")
        //@EndpointProperty(key = "ws-security.validate.token", value = "false")
    }
)


public interface MyService {
...
}
```

The ServerPasswordCallback is:

```
public class ServerPasswordCallback implements CallbackHandler {

    public ServerPasswordCallback() {
        System.out.println("Instantiating ServerPasswordCallback");
    }

    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException,
            UnsupportedCallbackException {

        System.out.println("Validating on ServerPasswordCallback");

        WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback) callbacks[0];

        if (pc.getIdentifier().equals("joe")) {
            // set the password on the callback. This will be compared to the
            // password which was sent from the client.
            pc.setPassword("password");
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that i get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.validate.UsernameTokenValidator.verifyDigestPassword(UsernameTokenValidator.java:176)
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.validate.UsernameTokenValidator.verifyPlaintextPassword(UsernameTokenValidator.java:136)
        at org.apache.wss4j.dom.validate.UsernameTokenValidator.validate(UsernameTokenValidator.java:94)
```

The sent message's header is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-3B91E43693FA4F34C61536922750459149">
      <wsse:Username>joe</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
      <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">ey+3J+OKoHlhfqREn7Q8jw==</wsse:Nonce>
      <wsu:Created>2018-09-14T10:59:10.459Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
    <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-3B91E43693FA4F34C61536922750459148">
      <wsu:Created>2018-09-14T10:59:10.459Z</wsu:Created>
      <wsu:Expires>2018-09-14T10:59:15.459Z</wsu:Expires>
    </wsu:Timestamp>
  </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

The strange thing is that seems that `ServerPasswordCallback` is never instantiated, and `handle()` is never called.
If in the Endpoint properties annotations i set `ws-security.validate.token` to `false`, the former Exception is thrown, even if this
property should prevent Token validation.
That fact make me think that annotations are not working, but i can't figure out why.
Is this the correct way of authenticating a `UsernameToken`?
Are the Endpoint properties annotations correct?

N.B. I can't set Endpoint properties like suggested in the [documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html#WS-Security-AddingtheinterceptorsviatheAPI) because I have not access to Endpoint instance. **A sample project is available [here](https://github.com/capozx/WSDLTest)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out a solution:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", name = "MyService")

@EndpointProperties(value = {
        @EndpointProperty(key = "webservice.security.authMethod", value = "WS-SECURITY")
        @EndpointProperty(key = "ws-security.callback-handler", value = "org.tempuri.ServerPasswordCallback")
    }
)


public interface MyService {
...
}
```

In order to make the annotations working, it's necessary to include the following annotation in the EndpointProperties:

```
@EndpointProperty(key = "webservice.security.authMethod", value = "WS-SECURITY")
```